# Parallel protractor tests are running in sequential order

Tags: angular, protractor

i was trying to achieve parallelism in protractor test specs. But the execution happens in sequential.

I have tried all the solutions mentioned in the related question's answers in stack overflow. This probably is a thing in this latest version of protractor.

the config file:

```
    exports.config = {
        framework: "jasmine",
        seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
        multiCapabilities: [
        {
            browserName: "firefox"
        },
        {
            browserName: "chrome"
        }],
    specs: ["todo-spec.js"],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
        }
    };
```

i expect tho browser to simultaneously open and execute the given test specs simultaneously as stated in the official documentation. However the result contradicts. In this case, the firefox opens completes the e2e test process, firefox closes and the chrome repeats the same in sequential order.
I would be grateful if anyone could get me out of this trouble.

Comment: What is your full conf file?

Comment: i've updated the conf file.. so you can see the whole file. i have tried sequential=false, that doesn't work either, i have tried maxInstances = 2 , doesn't work, tried maxSessions = 2 doesn't work...

Comment: This might be a bug since switching to Jasmine 3.3. I thought this was resolved but I'm going to look into it.

Comment: @cnishina Do you have any fix or work around for it though?

Comment: I have some thoughts on this is here https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5145 I'll have time next week to look at this.